# How to ignore lines in sql query which specific id php

Tags: sql

I have a simply shop with php and I need to ignore some products in shop on manage page. How to possible to make ignore in SQL query?

Here is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, 
                 a.user as puser, 
                 a.id as pid, 
                 b.date as date, 
                 b.price as price, 
                 b.job_id as job_id, 
                 b.masterkey as masterkey 
          FROM table_shop a 
          INNER JOIN table_shop_s b ON a.id = b.buyid 
          WHERE b.payok = 1 
          ORDER BY buyid";
```

I need to ignore list with `product_id = "3","4"` from table `table_shop_s` in this query

Comment: SELECT a.*, a.user as puser, a.id as pid, b.date as date, b.price as price, b.job_id as job_id, b.masterkey as masterkey FROM table_shop a INNER JOIN table_shop_s b ON a.id = b.buyid WHERE b.payok = 1 and b.product_id not in(3,4) ORDER BY buyid;

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE b.payok = 1 AND tablename.product_id != 3 AND tablename.product_id != 4
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [NOT IN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php) (to ignore specific `pids`), with [AND](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php) logical condition. Use the following:

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, 
                 a.user as puser, 
                 a.id as pid, 
                 b.date as date, 
                 b.price as price, 
                 b.job_id as job_id, 
                 b.masterkey as masterkey 
          FROM table_shop a 
          INNER JOIN table_shop_s b ON a.id = b.buyid 
          WHERE b.payok = 1 
            AND a.id NOT IN (3,4) 
          ORDER BY buyid";
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answer has noted you would probably use a "productid NOT IN (3,4)" which would work, but that would be a short-term fix.  Extend the thinking a bit.  2 products now, but in the future you have more you want to hide / prevent?  What then, change all your queries and miss something?

My suggestion would be to update your product table.  Add a column such as ExcludeFlag and have it set to 1 or 0... 1 = Yes, Exclude, 0 = ok, leave it alone.  Then join your shop detail table to products and exclude when this flag is set...  Also, you only need to "As" columns when you are changing their result column name,  Additionally, by doing A.*, you are already getting ALL columns from alias "a" table, do you really need to add the extra instances of "a.user as puser, a.id as pid" ?

something like

```
SELECT 
      a.*, 
      b.date, 
      b.price, 
      b.job_id, 
      b.masterkey
   FROM 
      table_shop a
         INNER JOIN table_shop_s b 
            ON a.id = b.buyid 
           AND b.payok = 1 
           INNER JOIN YourProductTable ypt
              on b.ProductID = ypt.ProductID
             AND ypt.ExcludeFlag = 0
   ORDER BY 
      a.id
```

Notice the extra join and specifically including all those where the flag is NOT set.
Also, good practice to alias table names closer to context of purpose vs just "a" and "b" much like my example of long table YourProductTable aliased as ypt.

I also changed the order by to "a.id" since that is the primary table in your query and also, since a.id = b.buyid, it is the same key order anyhow and probably is indexed on your "a" table too.  the table_shop_s table I would assume already has an index on (buyid), but might improve when you get a lot of records to be indexed on (buyid, payok) to better match your JOINING criteria on both parts.